# Regex match word with optional length

Tags: regex

I need to match word as fully as possible. There is minimum "base", and then everything else is optional. For example, word "running" with base "run" should match longest among "run, runn, runni, runnin, running"

I came up with this solution: `/run(?:ning|nin|ni|n)?/`, it works, but it is not pretty.

`/run[ning]*/` also works, it is pretty but it is fuzzy, can have errors (runnnnning).

Is it possible to use conditions: if "run" is followed by "n", select it, if this "n" followed by "i" select it ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think your existing solution is OK; I doubt you'll find a way to make it much clearer. The only real alternative approach I can suggest would be to write this as:

```
/run(?:n(?:n(?:i(?:n(?:g)?)?)?)?)?/
```

...But that's much more confusing in my opinion!

However, you could instead focus on writing a helper method to abstract this complexity away. For example:

```
def partial_word_regex(word, min_length)
  # e.g. ["ning", "ing", "ng", "g", ""]
  extensions = 0.upto(word.length - min_length).map { |n| word[min_length..-n-1] }

  # e.g. /run(?:ning|nin|ni|n|)/
  /#{word[0..min_length-1]}(?:#{extensions.join('|')})/
end

# Usage:
partial_word_regex("running", 3)
```

Comment: Your first regex will always match only `runn`, even from `running` as order matters among alternations. Second can be somewhat shorter by using `(?:ng?)?` for the innermost group.

Comment: Yeah, true - since the "longest match" was specified, the order should be preserved as OP did.

Comment: With regard to that regex shorten you suggest @SebastianProske, you're absolutely right - but I wanted to keep this answer as generic as possible since it simplifies the task of abstracting the logic into a helper method.